# two or more range inputs sharing one (the same) Max value in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

To give you an image of what I am trying to do, know that browser strategy real time games page when you can recruit units using an range input (or ui slider)? Something like this...
 I am trying to make some range inputs that should share the same max value (which is given dynamically by an ajax call). For example if I have value 10, when I change first range at value 3, rests of ranges will have max value 7 now. If I change value to second range at 2, rests will have now max 5...
I should simplify this for the moment with only 3 ranges (but will be more, like 14).

```
<input type="range" id="wpike" min="0" max="" value="0"><button>V</button>  
<input type="range" id="waxe" min="0" max="" value="0"><button>V</button>  
<input type="range" id="wsword" min="0" max="" value="0"><button>V</button>
```

Variable $rangemax will be given in ajax call and put in every range input max value... I tried to make an onchange event using ranges class, but that will trigger it over the actual range changed (minimizing its max value irremediable).

```
$('.ceva').on('change input', function () {
    var $rangemax = // $rangemax - wpike val - waxe val - wsword val(orientative)
        $('ceva').attr('max', $rangemax);
});
```

I can do an onchange function for each id separately like: when I change its value, change atrr max for every id (excluding changed id)... But this will result huge code, considering i should have like 14 ranges...
Or I can have an invisible input... When page is loaded, I fill its value with $rangemax. Ranges will have max Then $(ceva).on(change - insert in the input value ($rangemax-waxe.val()-wpike.val()-so on... Then set max attr of $(ceva) as insert element value?  Would be more elegant...but..not enought?:D

Comment: So, their combined value should less than max-value?

Comment: Why do you even need event? `$(".ceva").each(function () { $(this).attr("max", $rangemax) });`

Comment: Ajax returns max value for all soldiers? And that number is then distributed on all the sliders?

Comment: On first look on page, $('.ceva').attr("max", $rangemax); , so, yes. Ajax will return max val for all. Then, (max value is global) when I change one range, or two, i want to recalculate it and put it as max only for remaining untouched ranges(with value 0)...at least, that should be a solution as I think...

Comment: Something like this, dfsq, but that won t work, because $rangemax is recalculated when I change one range, and will insert in the current changed range max $rangedmax - self value(of changed range). I there would be a solution to exclude id s with value over 0 from ",each"...

Answer (score 0):

after a marathon effort, I have what u want;

Change first scroll ("wpike"); based on that other two will be set such that waxe+wsword  = 10 -wpike;

Note: this works only for 3; scaling upto 14 is something that needs more thought;

```js
window.onload = changeEvent()

function changeEvent() {
  let allInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="range"]');
  let allIds = [];
  for(i=0;i<allInputs.length;i++) {
   allIds.push(allInputs[i].getAttribute('id'));
     allInputs[i].onchange = function(e) {
       let idOfScrolledSlider = (e.path[0].getAttribute('id'));       
       changeSliders(allIds,idOfScrolledSlider)
     }     
  }
}

function changeSliders(allIds,idOfScrolledSlider) {
 let cleanedIdArray = popId(allIds,idOfScrolledSlider)
  let firstScrollValue = document.getElementById(idOfScrolledSlider).value; 
  document.getElementById('waxe').value = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 -firstScrollValue));
  let secondScrollValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * (firstScrollValue))
  document.getElementById('wsword').value =10 - (parseInt(firstScrollValue) + parseInt(secondScrollValue));  
  console.log('firstScrollValue',firstScrollValue);
  console.log('secondScrollValue',secondScrollValue);
  console.log('3rd scoll', 10 - (parseInt(firstScrollValue) + parseInt(secondScrollValue)));
}

function popId(allIds,idOfScrolledSlider) {
  let newArray = [];
  allIds.map((id) => {
     if(id != idOfScrolledSlider) newArray.push(id);
  });   
   return newArray;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="wpike" min="0" max="10" value="10"><button>V</button>  
<input type="range" id="waxe" min="0" max="" value="0"><button>V</button>  
<input type="range" id="wsword" min="0" max="" value="0"><button>V</button>
```

Comment: Ty so much for effort! I will study your code at home, I ve found there some new things to learn, at a first view, i will check their refferences

Comment: I will upvote your answer because you gave me some new things to learn. Is not what I look for, because I want to have like 3 resources and every soldier cost different resources amount... That will complicate things more. Thank you, I ve learned something new from you!

Comment: Sorry Rajkumar Somasundaram for retrieving my vote, you worked hard there and I will honor you later for lesson you gave to me (some methods there never used or heard before, you started me a good documentation marathon).

Comment: Though I am sad that u retrieved the vote, I am thankful to u for making me think; latter is key reason why I come to stackOverFlow. I hope u find the solution for all of ur problem statements; cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, was so simple...just math...sorry for my incompetence, I will let this here, maybe someone would find it useful.

```
<input type="range" class="ceva" id="a" min="0" max="10" value="0">  
<input type="range" class="ceva" id="b" min="0" max="10" value="0">
<input type="range" class="ceva" id="c" min="0" max="10" value="0"> 

 $(".ceva").on("change", function(){
 var maxi = 10;
 var a = $("#a").val();
 var b = $("#b").val();
 var c = $("#c").val();
 $('#a').attr("max" , (maxi - b - c));
 $('#b').attr("max" , (maxi - a - c));
 $('#c').attr("max" , (maxi - a - b));
 });
```

Now I have to work on part where I have 3 resources and different costs for every soldier.